# Save and load checkboxes state to file

Tags: javascript, json, file

I want to save state of selected checkbox to a file (whether as a text file or something else) that contains information on what was checked.

I can't use localstorage or cookies, I need it saved as external file so I can save (and load) several files with different checkmarks selected.

It's pretty straightforward, but I can't find any solution that does exactly this, so any help is appreciated.

Simple snippet for reference:

```css
div {
    display: table;
}

span {
  display: block;
}

input,
label {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
    <input id="box1" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="box1">Checkbox 1</label>
  </span>
  
  <span>
    <input id="box2" type="checkbox" checked/>
    <label for="box2">Checkbox 2</label>
  </span>
  
  <span>
    <input id="box3" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="box3">Checkbox 3</label>
  </span>
</div>
<button id="_save">Save</button>
<button id="_load">Load</button>
```

Comment: You question has nothing with ajax, also you are missing the tag javascript. Please show us something that you tried...

Comment: Thanks for the tag help, but I don't have any viable attempts. All I've managed to find is solution for localstorage (several of them in fact), but nothing on external saving/loading. Even a simple reference page would be a huge help.

Comment: Your checkboxes are part of a `<form>`.  When the save button is clicked, the state of all `<input>` fields in the form will be sent to the page you defined as the action to the form.  You then use a server side language (ex. PHP or .NET) to read these states and save the information to a file.  References for PHP (since that is what I know most): https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp, https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file.asp to get you started, http://php.net for all the details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I understand that's how the form works, but do you thing there is any way to save those states before submitting?

Comment: If you don't want to save the data to the browser (e.g. using localstorage), then submitting the form is the first part of the act of saving the information - you send the data to the webserver, which then runs some code to receive the data and save it somewhere (e.g. in a database, or a file, whatever you need). You can't save it to a file on the local machine where the browser is running, if that's what you're asking - browsers are deliberately sandboxed to disallow that kind of thing, otherwise malicious websites could do unpleasant things to a user's disk.

Comment: I think I might have solved it, I actually can use localstorage and than import/export localstorage as a file.

Comment: how are you going to export to a file? I'd be intrigued to know the solution for that, as far as I know the most you can do is prompt the user/browser to potentially download a file, which they may refuse to do. Or you send the file to a server via a HTTP request (but in that case, you might as well just use a form submit directly).

Comment: localstorage will only exist as long as the browser is open.  If you need a file locally, then a cookie is the way to go because it could loaded after the browser closes.  If you can have a user interaction, then maybe you can load an iframe with the data and then request that the user download this "file".  But then to load it, you'd have to ask the user to upload the file.  It becomes hectic.  But to save it to a file on the server, you'd have to submit the form, and let the server handle the data save to a file.

Comment: I will answer my own question later on, when I form the complete solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have a solution that does what I needed.

So when you check everything you want from your form, you can save it into localstorage and THEN you can export localstorage as JSON. I found this google extension that handles import and export for the localstorage (in a textual file), but you can always go extra mile and write your own script for that.

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxoqgy02/) for the localstorage so can save whatever input you want and here is chrome extension that handles import and export [LocalStorage Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/localstorage-manager/fkhoimdhngkiicbjobkinobjkoefhkap).

Javascript:

```
;(function($) {
    $.fn.toJSON = function() {
        var $elements = {};
        var $form = $(this);
        $form.find('input, select, textarea').each(function(){
          var name = $(this).attr('name')
          var type = $(this).attr('type')
          if(name){
            var $value;
            if(type == 'radio'){
              $value = $('input[name='+name+']:checked', $form).val()
            } else if(type == 'checkbox'){
              $value = $(this).is(':checked')
            } else {
              $value = $(this).val()
            }
            $elements[$(this).attr('name')] = $value
          }
        });
        return JSON.stringify( $elements )
    };
    $.fn.fromJSON = function(json_string) {
        var $form = $(this)
        var data = JSON.parse(json_string)
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
          var $elem = $('[name="'+key+'"]', $form)
          var type = $elem.first().attr('type')
          if(type == 'radio'){
            $('[name="'+key+'"][value="'+value+'"]').prop('checked', true)
          } else if(type == 'checkbox' && (value == true || value == 'true')){
            $('[name="'+key+'"]').prop('checked', true)
          } else {
            $elem.val(value)
          }
        })
    };
}( jQuery ));

//
// DEMO CODE
// 
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#_save").on('click', function(){
     console.log("Saving form data...")
     var data = $("form#myForm").toJSON()
     console.log(data);
     localStorage['form_data'] = data;

     return false;
   })

   $("#_load").on('click', function(){
     if(localStorage['form_data']){
       console.log("Loading form data...")
       console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage['form_data']))
       $("form#myForm").fromJSON(localStorage['form_data'])
     } else {
       console.log("Error: Save some data first")
     }

     return false;
   })
});
```

HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="get" id="myForm">

<input type="text" name="textfield">
Textfield
<br/>

<input type="number" name="numberfield" />
Numberfield
<br/>

<input type="radio" name="radiofield" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="radiofield" value="2" />
<input type="radio" name="radiofield" value="3" />
Radiofields
<br/>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkfield">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkfield2">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkfield3">
Checkboxes
<br/>

<select name="selectbox">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
Selectbox
<br/>

<textarea name="textarea"></textarea>
Textarea
<br/>

<hr/>
<button id="_save">Save</button>
<button id="_load">Load</button>
<input type="reset">

</form>
```

Comment: and if instead on the local manager, isn't better on local file? So that there is even the portability?